# Rails server not starting on Port 3000 "TCPServer Error: Permission denied - bind (2)"

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I installed Ruby on Rails, MySQL Server 5.6, and the mysql2 gem on my Windows 7 computer.  MySQL Server 5.6 runs on port 3000.  My database.yml file is:

```
# MySQL2
#   gem install mysql2
#   Ensure the mysql2 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'mysql2'
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: demo1_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: root
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 3000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: demo1_test
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: root
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 3000

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: demo1
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: root
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 3000
```

I ran "bundle install" with the following Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.2'

# Use mysql2 as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

gem 'devise'

gem 'protected_attributes'

gem 'terminator'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.1.2'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

I could run the "bundle install", "rake db:create" and "rake db:migrate" commands without any problems.  I started the MySQL server and typed "rails s" in the command line.  The result was the following:
WARN  TCPServer Error:  Permission denied - bind (2)
Exiting

I made sure to open port 3000 in Windows Firewall, and allow rails to communicate through the firewall.

Typing "rails s -p 80" works, and the web application works on localhost:80, but the fields won't work because MySQL Server will not run on port 80.

Am I missing something?  How can I get the Rails server and web app to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to run both the database AND the rails web server on port 3000.

EDIT: To clarify, you should probably run the rails server at port 3000 (the default), and run mysql on a different port.

Whatever port you run mysql on, put that port in your database.yml settings under "port:".

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I reinstalled the MySQL database, configured it to Port 3306, and changed the database.yml file to use port 3306.  "rails s" now works without the error message, but when I type "http://localhost:3306" the web application will not come up;  I get a "download" at the bottom of my browser window.  When I type "http://localhost:3000" the web application will come up, but the fields do not read any of the data I type in; the app still sees them as blank.

Comment: localhost:3000 is what you want in the browser to view the rails site.

Comment: Thank you.  The web page appears when I type localhost:3000, but problem is that even though I enter data into the fields, the web app doesn't "see" them there.  For example, I enter my e-mail address and password into two fields, click the Submit button, and get the message:  "Email cannot be blank.  Password cannot be blank."  How do I configure the MySQL database to look at the Rails web app?

Comment: That sounds like validation is failing for some reason. I don't think that's a database issue, I think that's a controller or view issue. For some reason when you submit your form, either the HTML in your view isn't sending the email and password to the controller, or the controller isn't putting them into the model before trying to save it.

Comment: If you want to make sure the rails app is talking to the database correctly, try using "rails console" instead to create an instance of your model, and save it. If that works, the database part is working.

Comment: PS: If my answer worked for you, you could always "accept" it so I can earn some internet points to feed my family. ;)

Comment: Thank you for your help.  It does look like a controller or view issue.  How do I check the controller and view to determine whether or not they are working the way I want them to?  I am new (within the last month) to Ruby on Rails, so that is why I am asking so many questions.

Comment: Where did the controller and view code come from? Scaffolds?

Comment: I don't know.  One of my colleagues gave it to me.  It could be from a previous version of Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using port 3306? This is what my connection string looks like and it works fine.

```
staging:
 adapter: mysql2
 encoding: utf8
 host: 10.0.0.16
 database: my_database
 port: 3306
 username: my_username
 password: my_password
```

Note that the port of your webserver and your database are two different things. I run my webserver normally on port 3000 and mysql on 3306. I think 3306 is the default port used for mysql.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I reinstalled the MySQL database, configured it to Port 3306, and changed the database.yml file as above.  "rails s" now works without the error message, but when I type "http://localhost:3306" the web application will not come up;  I get a "download" at the bottom of my browser window.  When I type "http://localhost:3000" the web application will come up, but the fields do not read any of the data I type in; the app still sees them as blank.

Comment: Can you post your database yaml file? if the yaml file in your post is still the same, it need to be updated. If not can you post your updated yaml file. You should be typing localhost:3000 in you browser to access the application. The database and port 3306 is something separate that relates to the database.

Comment: development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: demo1_development
  username: root
  password: root
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 3306

test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: demo1_test
  username: root
  password: root
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 3306

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: demo1
  pool: 1000
  username: root
  password: root
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 3306

Comment: Is sql services running? Can you log into your instance of mysql and see the actual database created in mysql workbench after running your db migration scripts.